# Plot a bar chart as subplot in a for loop from a table so that it updates at each iteration w.r.t row elements

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, matlab-figure

I have several subplots in a for loop of subjects. I want to plot the subject wise performance from a 20x2 table. How do I make a separate subplot- a barchart on the same figure in a way that at first iteration it updates and plot the elements of 1st row as Space and Time respectively, then on 2nd iteration that of second row and so on, from the performance table? An excerpt from my code is given below.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best,
A

```
for s=1:size(SubjectFolder,2)
                    % ..... some code
figure(1)
 subplot(423)
                        f_psd = Grand_AvgTF_Space.freq;
                        [trash,f_psd_plot] = min(abs(f_psd-which_f)); 
                        PSD = mean(abs(squeeze(Grand_AvgTF_Space.powspctrm(s,:,:,:))),3); % [ch x freq] PSD of space or time condition          
                        semilogy(f_psd,PSD,'color','b')
                        hold on, 
                        semilogy(f_psd, mean(PSD),'linewidth',3,'color','r')
                        hold on
                        line([which_f which_f],[min(PSD(:)) max(PSD(:))],'color','g','linewidth',3)
                        xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
                        ylabel('Power (dB/Hz)')
                        title( 'Space' )
                        ylim([min(PSD(:)) max(PSD(:))])
                        title( 'Space' )
    subplot(424), % topoplot space
                    data_megin.avg = repmat(PSD(:,f_psd_plot),1,length(data_megin.time));
                    cfg.parameter        = 'avg' %
                    ft_topoplotER(cfg, data_megin );
                    title(['Topolot for Space Freq = ' num2str(f_psd(f_psd_plot)) ' Hz'])
                    
                    %..... some code
            end 
        
            % 20x2 Table looks like this without variable names. Suppose I wanna give 1st col name as Space and 2nd col as Time in the required subplot, where each row represents subject1 to subject20.
            96   100
            85   89
            .     .
            .     .
            80    87
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on the lines of this might work, Unfortunately, without the data I resorted to using placeholder plots. The size and colours of the bar graph can most likely be changed as well. Here I assume the topographical plots can take a subplot slot without any issues. I'm not familiar enough with the plotting characteristics/behaviour of topographical plots to judge if this will work as expected.

For a smaller bar graph change this line from:

```
subplot(4,3,[3 6 9 12]); Bar_Graph = bar(Bar_Data);
```

to:

```
subplot(4,3,[6 9]); Bar_Graph = bar(Bar_Data);
```

[image: Subplots Using Multiple Slots]

```
Table = round(100*rand(20,2));
Placeholder = zeros(500,1000);

for Figure_Index = 1: 20

figure(Figure_Index);
subplot(4,3,1); imshow(Placeholder); title("Plot 1");
subplot(4,3,2); imshow(Placeholder); title("Topoplot 1");
subplot(4,3,4); imshow(Placeholder); title("Plot 2");
subplot(4,3,5); imshow(Placeholder); title("Topoplot 2");
subplot(4,3,7); imshow(Placeholder); title("Plot 3");
subplot(4,3,8); imshow(Placeholder); title("Topoplot 3");
subplot(4,3,10); imshow(Placeholder); title("Plot 4");
subplot(4,3,11); imshow(Placeholder); title("Topoplot 4");

Bar_Data = Table(Figure_Index,:);
subplot(4,3,[3 6 9 12]); Bar_Graph = bar(Bar_Data);
text(1:length(Bar_Data),Bar_Data,num2str(Bar_Data'),'vert','bottom','horiz','center'); 
Bar_Graph.BaseLine.Visible = 'off';
axis off

end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you for your time. Actually m processing in another matlab implementd interface Fieldtrip toolbox so the behavior of topoplots is different than normal plots. But that's not gonna effect bars. I got the direction from this one so can work:)

Comment: @MicahelTr7 could you please also recommend how to create an interactive plot for the same. As you see in the main plot a green color line on power spectrum subplots. In topoplots you see it with a specific frequency value which is which_f freq in the code. I have to give different values in which_f vector to get topoplots on particular freq. Is there a way that we can create a slider which as we move on power spectrum plots, changes the color and frequency on topoplots w.r.t slider movement?

Comment: Yeah, that would have to be done using MATLAB GUI elements. That'd be pretty involved to be quite honest. You'd need to create a slider with a callback function that grabs the corresponding data and changes the topoplots accordingly.

Comment: I see, considering the above piece of code for subplots (423 & 424) how can I use  a callback function? m kinda beginner in matlab

Comment: It's a little bit out of the scope of what I can write in the comments but you would need to setup a `uifigure` first. Here's a GUI example that might give some implementation insight: [MATLAB - adding calibrated slider to figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615285/matlab-adding-calibrated-slider-to-figure/64617176#64617176).

Answer (score 1):

### Indicating Axes in `bar()` and `plot()` Calls

This might not exactly fit your exact use case but if you're simply looking to add a bar to a bar graph that is a part of a subplot on every iteration this example might help. Here the `subplot(4,2,3)` axes are assigned to the variable `Bar_Graph_Axes`. `Bar_Graph_Axes` can be called within the `bar()` call to indicate the specific axes to plot on. Passing axes names is a good way to modify existing plots since calling `hold on` will automatically allow you to modify the last called plot. Below is a playground script that you may modify to fit your implementation. The `pause(1)` is there for visualization purposes to show each bar being added.

[image: Bar Graph Subplot]

### Playground Script:

```
Number_Of_Graphs = 20;

Table = rand(20,2);
Table(:,1) = (1:20);

for Graph_Index = 1: Number_Of_Graphs
    
Bar_Graph_Axes = subplot(4,2,3); 
hold on
bar(Bar_Graph_Axes,Table(Graph_Index,1),Table(Graph_Index,2));
title("Bar Graph Subplot");
pause(1);

end
```

---

### If Data is Already Formatted in Array

If the data is simply in an array where the categories are defined by the columns calling the function `bar()` will automatically make a double bar graph in this case.

[image: Double Bar Graph]

```
Number_Of_Iterations = 20;
Performance_Space_Time = rand(Number_Of_Iterations,2);
bar(Performance_Space_Time);
xticks(1:Number_Of_Iterations);
title("Bar Graph");
xlabel("Iteration, s"); ylabel("Value");
legend("Space","Time");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you for your ans, i appreciate that. But by same Fig i meant the fig of all subplots where I have 8 subplots of power spectrum + topoplots. Then i wanna add a 9th subplot of bar chart displaying the value of performance wrt S loop. When s=1st subj, there should be a 2 bars showing the values 96 (space) and 100 (time) respectively then s=2, bar values 85 and 89 and so on. Hope you get my point. I tried one way using suptitle and converting table variables num2str which works perfectly but you know it will give values in the main title. I'll try your approach if that works

Comment: I think it'll take me a bit of time to understand the whole context of the question. Any possibility, that you could simplify your question to make it more minimal. A diagram is also appreciated if it cannot be simplified. Stack Overflow questions work best when a lot of context isn't essential to answer.

Comment: I think uploading a pic could make it more easier but unfortunately I can't upload pic here as m new user so it says i need to have 10+ reputations to upload a pic. I'll try to figure out

Comment: To get this straight is it a double bar chart that you want? Where each each entry (subject) has a bar representing `space` and another bar representing `time`? Or is this data somehow supposed to be plotted against each other?

Comment: Exactly, each entry (subject) should have a bar representing space and another bar representing time from the given table. But it should be according to the iteration 's'.

Comment: So on each iteration, `s` you want to plot two bars one 'space' and one 'time'. So on iteration 1, you'll have 2 bars on iteration 2, you'll have 4 bars and so on?

Comment: Why not plot everything at once after the loop? You basically need to make a double bar graph from that array in the screenshot.

Comment: I've uploaded my main plot. On each iteration, s I want to plot two bars one 'space' and one 'time'. So on iteration 1, I'll have 2 bars on iteration 2 and so on iteration nth. Hope you get my point now. In the main title you can see I've space_perf etc which is from that table. To plot everything at once after the loop is way easier but i dont want that. I want to compare bars with power spectrum plots which you can see in the main_plot. For example in table row 1 is subj1, row2 subj2 so on. So 2 bars for each subject on each iteration. Which means there will be a 9th subplot for each subj.

Comment: So at end will you have 40 bars?  I think it is best to draw/sketch your expected output plot. That’s what I meant by a picture. I’m guessing you want subject along the horizontal axis.

Comment: Well you're not getting my point 2 bars for each subject on the main plot corresponding to the perf data, of course that will make 40 bars but not on one pic but on 20 pics. I've drwan what i want on the main plot.

Comment: You want each topoplot which is a sub-figure to have two bars corresponding to the time and space, correct?

Comment: Not for each topoplot, only one bar chart (to have two bars corresponding to the time and space) on the main plot. I've plotted one bar plot with only two bars. This bar chart tells us that a subject has 96% and 100% correct responses for space & time respectively, on a task. Now I can compare this percentage of correct responses with the behavior of signals looking at both power spectrum and topoplots. I can see where a particular subject is struggling on space and time condition etc. Yellow color is for time which is high both in topo and bar chart. This is just a way of data visualization)

Comment: I think I got it. You essentially want it formatted exactly like the screenshot. Are you going to have 20 different figure windows then or do you want them all in one window.

Comment: Each subject will have the 4 graphs, 4 topoplots and then 1 bar graph correct (with one space bar and one time bar)?  They’re 20 subjects which will add up to 20 times your screenshot with the correct data respectively.

Comment: Exactly like the screenshot. Yess each subject will have the 4 signal graphs, 4 topoplots and then 1 bar graph (with one space bar and one time bar). Yes 20 different windows for 20 subjs. It would be a great idea to have them all on one window but that will be a mess to visualize or if you can suggest a way to better visualize on one window